# Can't read PNG from IPA

Tags: java, png, javax.imageio

[image: icon.png]

I'm not able to read PNG files extracted from IPAs.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("z:\\icon.PNG"));
```

> throws: " I/O error reading PNG header".

I can read any other PNG, as long as it's not coming from an IPA.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's an IPA? If you're seeing that error, it almost certainly means that the png file is corrupt / not a valid png file, which would tend to suggest the extraction process is at fault (in which case we'd need to see whatever code extracted the png to help.)

Comment: An .ipa file is an iOS application archive file which stores an iOS app. It's basically just a zip file.  You can rename any ipa file to zip, and extract the PNG file.

Comment: Cool - as above, we'd need to see the code you're using to extract the png from the IPA (or zip) file. That's probably where the problem lies (check if "icon.PNG" will open in a normal image editor to be sure.)

Comment: I'm using ZipInputStream to open the IPA, then save the PNG locally.  But, as I indicated before, it doesn't matter how I extract it.  I can extract it manually, and I still get the same error. Microsoft's Edge can display it fine, Chrome can't.  Obviously, there is some special handling needed, thanks to Apple.

Comment: I'd like to see the PNG (binary). I know how the file format works so I can analyze it by hand to see what's off.

Comment: It's attached to the top of this question, icon.png.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It's not a PNG. It's a [CgBI](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) file, which is Apple's proprietary PNG extension. Most software can't read them, simply because they break the PNG spec, by inserting a custom CgBI critical chunk before the IHDR.

There's software (as found in the link above) than can read and convert them to standard PNGs. There's also a [Java based solution](https://github.com/viphe/ipng-converter) available (haven't tested it myself), that you may want to check out.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for your help!  I'll look into that.

Comment: That worked.  It would bee less confusing if Apple used its own file extension.

Comment: Perhaps. But software that identifies files by inspecting the file contents, would still identify the file as a PNG, so they would need to change the "magic" identifier as well. Instead, Apple could have added an extra chunk *AFTER* the IHDR, to specify the RGBA -> BGRA order, and otherwise kept the format as is.  This would allow all PNG software to read them, they would just display incorrectly unless there was special support. But I guess the rationale is that this is just an "internal format" used exclusively by Apple software...